# Expected Float but value was a java.lang.Double

Tags: android, floating-point, double

Activity_A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_A.this,
                            Activity_B.class);
intent.putExtra("user_lat",
                    getSharedPreferences(
                    Activity_C.USER_PREFS, 0).getFloat(
                    "lat", 0));
Log.d("lat from prefs = ",
            getSharedPreferences(Activity_C.USER_PREFS, 0)
            .getFloat("lat", 0));
intent.putExtra("lng",
                    getSharedPreferences(
                    Activity_C.USER_PREFS, 0).getFloat(
                    "user_lng", 0));
Log.d("lng from prefs = ",
            getSharedPreferences(Activity_C.USER_PREFS, 0)
            .getFloat("lng", 0)");
```

The Logcat shows:

**12-01 12:36:53.409: D/lat from prefs =(554): 18.599348**

**12-01 12:36:53.409: D/lng from prefs =(554): 73.7625**

and Activity_B:

```
    try {

        MyLat = this.getIntent().getDoubleExtra("user_lat", 0);
        MyLng = this.getIntent().getDoubleExtra("user_lng", 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("Exception in getting user lat and lng as Double",
                e.toString());
    }
    if (MyLat == 0.0 || MyLng == 0.0) {

        try {

            MyLat = this.getIntent().getFloatExtra("user_lat", 0);
            MyLng = this.getIntent().getFloatExtra("user_lng", 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Exception in getting user lat and lng as Float",
                    e.toString());
        }
    }

    Log.d("MyLat and MyLng", MyLat + "+" + MyLng);
```

and LogCat:

**12-01 12:36:57.168: D/MyLat and MyLng(554): 18.599348068237305+0.0**

and the LogCat error:

```
12-01 12:36:57.138: W/Bundle(554): Key user_lat expected Double but value was a java.lang.Float.  The default value 0.0 was returned.
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at android.os.Bundle.getDouble(Bundle.java:1017)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at android.content.Intent.getDoubleExtra(Intent.java:3377)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at com.wicfy.mobileapp.MapMarkerActivity.onCreate(MapMarkerActivity.java:60)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-01 12:36:57.159: W/Bundle(554):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I thought, since i am taking **user_lat** as a double in Activity_B, i must cast it to **double** during **intent.putExtra**

but then i get this in LogCat:

**12-01 12:36:57.168: D/MyLat and MyLng(554): 0.0+0.0**

```
12-01 12:07:50.218: W/Bundle(498): Key user_lat expected Float but value was a java.lang.Double.  The default value 0.0 was returned.
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at android.os.Bundle.getFloat(Bundle.java:984)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at android.content.Intent.getFloatExtra(Intent.java:3360)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at com.wicfy.mobileapp.MapMarkerActivity.onCreate(MapMarkerActivity.java:71)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-01 12:07:50.249: W/Bundle(498):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get none of the **Log.e** message. May be because its an Internal Exception and doesn't cause a crash.

So, how can i get the actual values which i am sending throught intent from **Activity_A** in **Activity_B**

Thank You

Comment: I updated my answer with a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value is already stored in a SharedPreferences file, it seems the simplest answer is to not use the Intent.

In Activity B use:

```
float myLat = getSharedPreferences(Activity_C.USER_PREFS, 0).getFloat("lat", 0);
// Read the Longitude in the same way
```

---

You are *trying* to work with Doubles from a Location object (I assume) however SharedPreferences don't work with Doubles. You might be safer converting the Doubles to Strings and back. This way you don't gain or lose any precision going to and from Floats.

Answer (score 2):

While for primitives you can cast `double` to a `float` (with loss of precision) and `float` to a `double` (with no warnings), in case of `Float` and `Double` this won't work. So every time you put a `Float` into a `Bundle` you must be sure it's a `Float` and not a `Double`. Hope this helps.